# Evaluating $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

I can't calculate the following integral:
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx,$$
where $[a, b] \subset [0,1]$.

Can someone, please, give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint look up Euler Substitution

Comment: @MrYouMath: it is even easier than that.

Comment: Or geometrically, this is the integral (which is normalized by the factor $\pi/2$) that computes the arc length of $$ (x-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 + y^2 = \tfrac{1}{4},\qquad a\leq x\leq b \text{ and } y\geq 0.$$ The you can compute the integral using trigonometry only.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I intended to show a method which is applicable to a wider range of Integrals:).

Comment: @MrYouMath: I am perfectly fine with that idea, but I think it would be better to add a link to something explaining Euler's substitution, in such a case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $[a,b]\subsetneq[0,1]$, by setting $x=t^2$ we get:
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\arcsin\sqrt{b}-\arcsin\sqrt{a}\right)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as. ${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$. Use u-substituion with $u=\sqrt{x}, \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. It then becomes $\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{2}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm{d}u$. I'm sure you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Anoteher simple substitution exploiting the symmetry of the integrand: $x=1/2 + u \implies dx=du$.
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1/2+u)(1/2-u)}}du$$